# Gemini: IE11 doesn't work

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver, gemini, visual-testing

Could you please help with the following?

1. Tried to run Visual Test by Gemini
2. IE 11 doesn't run the gemini tests

   - **Selenium-standalone:** 3.7.1

Here is stack-trace:

```
[moveTo({"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"320a2146-d2b3-4868-accc-cb04927e6cb2"},0,0)] Error response status: 13, UnknownError - An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
```

From the [Selenium Wiki](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) it was investigated that the **moveTo** action is used in gemini library for calibrating browser but this feature is not worked in IEDriver. Here is file where the moveTo action is used: [link to gemini file](https://github.com/gemini-testing/gemini/blob/f461f6521499a0f77155b01ffefedfb6a32b8208/lib/browser/index.js#L214)

```
gemini.reset = () => {}; - it doesn't work
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Here is code: **test.gemini.js**

```
    gemini.suite('test', (suite) => {
  suite.setUrl('/test')
    .setCaptureElements('[test]')
    .capture('email')
    .before((actions, find) => {
    this.emailField = find('input[name="email"]');
    this.usernameField = find('input[name="username"]');
    this.saveButton = find('test');
    })
    .capture('with text', (actions, find) => {
      actions.sendKeys(this.emailField, 'test');
    })
    .capture('click', (actions, find) => {
      actions.waitForElementToShow('input[name="username"]');
      actions.click(this.emailField);
    })
    .capture('hover', (actions, find) => {
      actions.mouseMove(this.emailField)
    })
    .capture('name with text', (actions, find) => {
      actions.sendKeys(this.usernameField, 'test test test 1074029859084*^@*($^)%)()9308')
    })
    .capture('click on save button', (actions) => {
      actions.click(this.saveButton);
    });
});
```

**.gemini.js**

```
module.exports = {
  rootUrl: 'http://localhost:7777',
  gridUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
  screenshotsDir: './screens',
  windowSize: '1600x1080',

  system: {
    plugins: {
      'html-reporter': {
        enabled: true,
        path: 'my/gemini-reports',
        defaultView: 'all',
        baseHost: 'test.com'
      }
    }
  },

  browsers: {
    // chrome: {
    //   desiredCapabilities: {
    //     browserName: 'chrome',
    //   }
    // },

    ie11: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'internet explorer',
        version: '',
        ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true,
        ignoreZoomSetting: true,
        requireWindowFocus: true,
        ensureCleanSession: true
      }
    },
  }
};
```

Comment: The possible solution of this issue is to use a another version of selenium.

Here is:

selenium-standalone install --version=2.47.0 --drivers.ie.version=2.53.1
selenium-standalone start --version=2.47.0 --drivers.ie.version=2.53.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible solution of this issue is to use a another version of selenium.
**Here is:**

```
selenium-standalone install --version=2.47.0 --drivers.ie.version=2.53.1

selenium-standalone start --version=2.47.0 --drivers.ie.version=2.53.1
```